# bootstrap, grid and scrolling

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap, angular and angular-ui-router

what I want to achieve is this mockup:

[image]

where the menu on the left is a navigation bar, a toolbar on the top, some breadcrumbs, content and a footer.

I *can* get all these elements in place. However, I need to populate the content with a variable number of elements from a rest data source. I want to wrap these nicely, so I am using the following angular / html

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 " ng-repeat-start="item in $ctrl.items">
      <div> card details here </div>
      <div class="clearfix" ng-if="$index % 3 === 2"></div>
      <div ng-repeat-end=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

this works, and shows all the data. However, as there is more data than can fit into the div, scrollbars appear *on the window*

What I would like to acheive is to get the scrollbar to appear *in the content div* , like the screenshot

I have tried all sorts of css, like `overflow: scroll-y`, but can't figure it out.

Comment: I guess a working fiddle would be the best to help in here. Anyways, it seems like you're using Bootstrap the wrong way. You may replace `col-lg-12` through `container`. I don't believe this will fix your issue but at least it's the only fix I can tell you right now, according to your code and my mind. :-)

Comment: thanks for the response - yeah - trying to untangle all the corporate stuff makes a fiddle a pain, but I'm working on it ;) Changing the "container" (or container-fluid) didn't make a difference though :(

Comment: Kinda hard to help without any proper code. The scrollbars you're writing of. Are they appearing vertically or horizontally?

Comment: vertically. I'm trying to get a jsfiddle, honest !

Comment: Without even seeing code, I assume you're running into some height problems. You might specify a height for your container (let's say 100px). That should solve your problem. After setting the height you'd be able to scroll inside of your container through `overflow`. You might test that before investigating time into a fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/6zwxdw7n/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to dynamic `heights`. Using fixed `heights` (also %, vh, ... are useable), you can get that layout to work properly. There are a lot of solutions for that.

**1. Using %**

If you're going to use %, and that would by far be the best option, you have to start at the root tag which basically is `<html>`. After that you've to add the proper height value to it's child elements you want to use. Keep in mind to start at `100%` and shrink your child element to the desired heights.

**2. Using vh**

The vh value is kinda same as %. You just don't need to set a height to every parent element. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6zwxdw7n/1/)

*Note: You may have to [check](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/length) if that's working with your target browser.*

**3. CSS3 calc() function**

Propably the newest method. You can calculate values through CSS(3), by using e.g. `calc(100% - 100px)`. That's pretty cool though, but also isn't supported by every browser. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

**4. Fixed layout**

You could also use some fixed positionings. Setting up your footer, header and nav to `position: fixed;` would also keep up everything smooth and clean. I'd use a fixed layout in order to get that done, since I'd like it the most. Also it doesn't have any incompatibility with legacy browsers.

Comment: turns out that a parent element didn't have the correct height information, so #1 was very helpful! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `overflow: scroll-y`,

please try:

```
height:100%;
overflow-y:scroll
```

*giving it a height enables the scroll bar to appear.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on my part. thanks for the help though